# Does $1/n$ converge to $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Does $1/n$ converge to $0$ on $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete metric, the question doesn’t specify the range ’$n$’ can take it just says $1/n$. So I’m assuming it’s a sequence with ‘$n$’ taking $\mathbb{R}$. Am I right to assume this.

And if I do, then it doesn’t converge in the discrete metric because the distance between the next term if the range were to be $\mathbb{R}$ would not be less than $1$, they would be larger. 
Is this correct?

Comment: I think the most conventional assumption would be that $n$ takes values over $\mathbb{N}$, not $\mathbb{R}$.  As for the convergence, what kinds of sequence converge in *any* metric space with discrete metric?

Comment: Cauchy sequences

Comment: Since you're talking about the limit as $n$ tends to $+\infty$, the convergence of the function $f(n) = 1/n$ doesn't depend on whether $n$ is an element of $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ because $\mathbb{N}$ is cofinal in $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. there is no real number larger than every natural number). However when talking about *sequences*, and especially when you're using the variable name "$n$", you typically take your indexing set to be $\mathbb{N}$; in particular if $n$ is considered an element of $\mathbb{R}$ then it doesn't make sense to say "next term".

Answer (score 3):

Only sequences that are eventually constant can converge in discrete metric.  Assume $1/n$ converges to $x$.  Then $\{x\}$ is an open set that only contains $x$ and doesn’t contain the tail of $1/n$. So a contradiction.